# rotate and moving circle

Tags: c++, animation, opengl, glut

I draw a circle with a + sign inside it to see it rotate

```
void drawcircle(float radius, float x, float y){
    float R = radius; // Radius of circle.
    float X = x; // X-coordinate of center of circle.
    float Y = y; // Y-coordinate of center of circle.
    int numVertices = 25; // Number of vertices on circle.
    float t = 0; // Angle parameter.
    int i;


    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT, GL_FILL );
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for(int i = 0; i < numVertices; ++i)
    {
        glVertex3f(X + R * cos(t), Y + R * sin(t), 0.0);
        t += 2 * PI / numVertices;
    }
    glEnd();

}
```

and in my display function I want to move it along the same path like a cars tyre and rotate it 30 degrees every time and towards the right of the screen like

```
glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(circle1_x, 0, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(30, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glTranslatef(-circle1_x, 0, 0.0f);
    drawcircle(20, circle1_x, 350.0);
glPopMatrix();
```

I translate it to a position and then rotate it and then translate it back to the same position but it comes off like as if moved only once and keeps moving across. I use the idle function and the glutIdleFunc(idle); to move the circle towards the right and reset it to the first position end of the screen.

How can I make it so that the circle can move and both rotate at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transformation matrix can be constructed as follows:

```
M = T * C * R * -C

//or with scale

M = T * C * R * SR * S * -SR * -C
```

where

**T:** position of the object (translation)
**C:** center of rotation (translation)
**R:** rotation
**SR:** scale orientation (rotation)
**S:** scale

In order to translate and rotate an object at the same time:

```
//set the position
glTranslatef(x, y, z);
//set the center of rotation (pivot point of the circle)
glTranslatef(dx, dy, dz);
//rotate around pivot point
glRotatef(rad, ax, ay, az);
//restore position
glTranslatef(-dx, -dy, -dz);
```

If you would construct your circle around the origin `(0,0)`, like

```
glVertex3f(radius_x * cos(rad), radius_y * sin(rad), z);
```

then you could omit unnecessary matrix multiplications and the above transformation would look like this:

```
//set the position (center of circle)
glTranslatef(x, y, z);
//rotate around center
glRotatef(rad, ax, ay, az);
```

**Note:** don't forget to set the proper matrix mode (it is not obvious in the presented code above)

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hard to explain without drawing. But i'll give it a try. When you first do your translate of circle_x (lets say its 10) you move your "drawing axis" to x=10, after that you rotate your "drawing axis" by 30 degrees. The problem comes when you "translate it back to the same position", because you did the rotation you wont be back at the same position you started. Try using glPushMatrix() and doing only the translation and rotation and after that draw and do glPopMatrix().